# Draw a line in Directx from given coordinates

Tags: visual-c++, directx-9

How can we draw a line between 2 points which are derived at run time? These are two 3 dimensional points in the 3D space.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Pretty easy.

use D3DPT_LINELIST as the first paramerter in the call to

```
IDirect3DDevice9::DrawPrimitive();
```

and  the geometry will be rendered as lines.

Best of Luck!